# Duplicate Config key

Tags: asp.net, .net, web-config

In `web.config`, why can't we have duplicate connection strings and handlers but on the other hand, we can have duplicates `<appSettings>` child elements with the same key name at the same level or down the inheritance hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

I don't this will complete answer to your question or not but I have some information that I would like to share.

If you look

```
ConfigurationManager.AppSettings
```

then it is NameValueCollection and If you give two key with same name default implementation will return latest value ( Last value in order for that key) but if you want to support multiple key support and you want it return all value for that key than you can replace appSettings default behavior with custom implementation.

```
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4302/How-to-make-AppSettings-work-with-multiple-values
```

But In case of connection string it is sealed class ConnectionStringSettingsCollection.

It is implement to support only one key with same name present and at web.config level it allow duplicate value for name but when you try to access it will throw error. It make sense in connection string case as well otherwise it get confused which to choose.

As per my point it is just implementing different way to support and reduce confusion.

Comment: @Firstly Thanks for your valuable comments:- But I want to know WHY ONLY in handlers and connection strings cases, it throws the exception.

Comment: Also In case of app setting it is not getting confused, as it is just taking the last one, then why it is getting confused in-cases of connection string and other. I am not getting the actual picture of the scenario.

Comment: You can replace in case on AppSetting if your project or requirement need to support multiple values for same key but for connection string and handler it is obivious that component are depend on that. Suppose connection string support this type of duplication then connection factory also get confused about the case as it is depend on that. Appsettings is depend on particular application component so it is quite aware of the change in implementation if it is provided.